# Required fields for Messaging Notification action in the flow

Tags: visual-workflow, error-messages, sms, action

I have a flow in which I send an SMS and use the Messaging Notification action for that. I pass all required fields to the action but in the Messaging Templates Error Log tab I see the error: You’re missing a required field. Make sure each required field has a valid value and try again.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem, you are missing recipient phone number, salesforce documentation on this part is misleading